# Index out of range, only inside function python

Tags: python-2.7, loops, indexing, append, indexoutofrangeexception

I really don't understand what is happening here.  I have a function:

```
def get_appliance_status(appliance):
    appliance_data = None
    status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_UNKNOWN
    status_message = 'No Appliance Data Available'

    try:
        appliance_data = ApplianceData.objects.filter(appliance=appliance).latest('timestamp')

    except Exception as ex:
        print ex
    else:
        if appliance_data:
            status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_OK
            status_message = 'Appliance Temperature and Pressure values are within designed ranges.'
            temperature_status = ''
            pressure_status = ''


            # status of inside box temp and food temps 1-4
            if appliance_data.temperature_4_f > appliance.max_temperature or \
               appliance_data.temperature_5_f > appliance.max_temperature or \
               appliance_data.temperature_6_f > appliance.max_temperature or \
               appliance_data.temperature_7_f > appliance.max_temperature or \
               appliance_data.temperature_8_f > appliance.max_temperature:
                status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_WARN
                temperature_status = 'Appliance Temperature is outside designed ranges. '
                status_message = temperature_status

            if est_obj > timestamp + timedelta(minutes=15) or \
               est_obj > timestamp + timedelta(minutes=15) and \
               appliance_data.temperature_4_f > appliance.max_temperature:
                status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_CRITICAL
                status_message = "Polar Board Has Lost Connection/Power Failure, Critical"
                #textclient.text(textclient.Brian, "Polar Board has lost connection" + " " + appliance.name)

            if appliance_data.power_1_amps > 0  and \
               appliance_data.power_2_amps == 0:
                status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_EMERGENCY
                status_message = "Condenser Motor Fail-Emergency"

            if appliance_data.power_1_amps == 0 and \
               appliance_data.power_2_amps > 0:
                status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_EMERGENCY
                status_message = "Compressor Motor Fail-Emergency"  

            if appliance_data.power_1_amps == 0 and \
               appliance_data.power_2_amps == 0 and \
               appliance_data.power_3_amps == 0 and \
               appliance_data.power_4_amps == 0:
                status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_EMERGENCY
                status_message = "Power failure- Emergency"

            if appliance_data.pressure_1_psi < 8 and \
               appliance_data.pressure_2_psi < 7 and \
               appliance_data.power_1_amps == 0 and \
               appliance_data.power_2_amps == 0 and \
               appliance_data.power_3_amps > 0 and \
               appliance_data.power_4_amps > 0:
                status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_EMERGENCY
                status_message = "No Pressure, Condenser/Compressor failure, Emergency"

            if appliance_data.pressure_1_psi > appliance.max_pressure_1 or \
               appliance_data.pressure_1_psi < appliance.min_pressure_1 or \
               appliance_data.pressure_2_psi > appliance.max_pressure_2 or \
               appliance_data.pressure_2_psi < appliance.min_pressure_2:
                status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_WARN
                status_message = ''
                pressure_status = 'Appliance Pressure is outside designed ranges.'
                status_message = ' '.join((temperature_status, pressure_status))

            if appliance_data.power_3_amps == 0 and \
               appliance_data.power_4_amps > 0:
                status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_CRITICAL
                status_message = "Evaporator Fan 1 Failure, Critical"

            if appliance_data.power_3_amps > 0 and \
               appliance_data.power_4_amps == 0:
                status_color = SENSOR_STATUS_COLOR_CRITICAL
                status_message = "Evaporator Fan 2 Failure, Critical "


            for item in my_appliance:
                if item.temperature_4_f > appliance.max_temperature:
                    above_temp.append(item.timestamp.astimezone(local_tz).strftime('%H:%M'))
                else:
                    break
            print(above_temp)

    return '<span class="status" style="background-color:' + status_color +';" title="' + status_message + '"></span>'
```

The problem lies here:

```
        above_temp=[]
        for item in my_appliance:
            if item.temperature_4_f > appliance.max_temperature:
               above_temp.append(item.timestamp.astimezone(local_tz)
              .strftime('%H:%M'))
            else:
                break
        print(above_temp)
```

If I try print `above_temp[0]`, I get an out of range error.  I can access the first element with `above_temp[0:1]`.  However, this returns a list of this element, this is not what I want.  When I `print(above_temp)` I get an `[]`, then after that I get the list that I want.  I really want the first and last element of this list.  The last element with change in index, based on len of list. If I run this same code outside of the function, it works as expected.  I need it to run inside this function though.  Why does it initially return an empty list and why can't I just use indexing to access elements inside this function?
Here is what I get when I run this:

```
[]
['11:17', '11:14', '11:12', '11:10', '11:08', '11:06', '11:04', '11:02',
 '11:00', '10:58', '10:56', '10:53', '10:51', '10:49', '10:47', '10:45', 
 '10:43', '10:41', '10:39', '10:37', '10:35', '10:32', '10:30', '10:28', 
 '10:26', '10:24', '10:22', '10:20', '10:18', '10:16', '10:14', '10:11', 
 '10:09', '10:07', '10:05', '10:03', '10:01', '09:59', '09:57', '09:55', 
 '09:53', '09:50', '09:48', '09:46', '09:44', '09:42', '09:40', '09:38', 
 '09:36', '09:34', '09:32', '09:29']
```

Comment: In the code you posted first there's no initialization for `above_temp`, and yet in the latter code snippet you do initialize `above_temp` with `[]`. Did you initialize it or did you not? If you did not then you may be accessing a global variable unknowingly.

Comment: No, I had it initialized outside of the function, so I moved it to clarify that I had initialized it

Answer (score 0):

List slicing is more lenient - it even works if the list does not entail the elements you are asking from it, it will return an empty list `[]` in that case.
Indexing into a list at an non-present location will return an Error.

Reproducable by:

```
tata = [] 

print  tata[0:200] 
try:
    print tata[0] 
except IndexError as idxerr:
    print idxerr
```

Output:

```
[]
list index out of range
```

---

See [Introduction](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html) in the Section about [Strings](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

> ```
> word = 'Python'
> ```
>
> Attempting to use an index that is too large will result in an error:
>
> ```
> word[42]  # the word only has 6 characters Traceback (most recent call last):   
>     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> IndexError: string
>     index out of range
> ```
>
> However, out of range slice indexes are handled
>       gracefully when used for slicing:
>
> ```
> word[4:42] 'on'
> word[42:] ''
> ```

---

If you need to acces the first and last element of a list you might consider doing this:

```
firstVal, lastVal = above_temp[0:1],above_temp[-1:] # both wont throw error, but 
                                                    # might be [] afterwards
```

Demo:

```
tata = [2,3]
firstVal, lastVal = tata[0:1],tata[-1:] 
print firstVal , lastVal

tata = []
firstVal, lastVal = tata[0:1],tata[-1:] 
print firstVal , lastVal
```

Output:

```
[2] [3]
[] []
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I understand the slicing method and that worked, however it returns another list, which is not what I wanted.  I figured it out, it was a problem with another device which was not sending information, so it was returning that empty array.  Therefore, I was getting an out of range error because it was empty.  I just added a check in there like this:

Comment: if len(above_temp)>0:  then it creates the variables that store the first and last elements, but only if they exist.